# clickable button to get data wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

### View.Xaml

```
 <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = dcCategory}" SelectedValuePath = "Key" SelectedValue = "{Binding Path = Category, Mode = TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <Button Content="Add Value" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddValue, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key.Name}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

My goal is to click Add Value and send selected item (Category type). Its right now it's working but not as I acepted.
Insted of clicking only  button, I have to click first blue area and then code 'catch' the 'Category' with data. Otherwise Category is null.

[example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oY6lYrAVQke7ap6ilVat6JJ8_2JshJ4Y)

### ViewModel

```
private Category _Category;
public Category Category
{
    get
    {
        return _Category;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_Category != value)
        {
            _Category = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Category);
        }
    }
}

    public ICommand AddValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (_AddValue == null)
            {
                _AddValue = new BaseCommand(() => Messenger.Default.Send(CategoryValueCode.AddValue + "," + Category.CategoryId));
            }
            return _AddValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use an ICommand implementation that accepts a parameter and send the current to the command as a CommandParameter?

Answer (score 0):

That's logic, because your button's command will be executed before `ListView.SelectedValue` is set. You can change it, if you handle `PreviewMouseDown` for the `Button`. I also found it better to set `ListView.SelectionMode` to `Single`.

```
<ListView ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = dcCategory}" SelectedValuePath = "Key" SelectedValue = "{Binding Path = Category, Mode = TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single">
<Button Content="Add Value" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddValue, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" PreviewMouseDown="PreviewMouseDown"/>
```

```
private void PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = null;
    var visParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as FrameworkElement);
    while (lvi == null && visParent != null)
    {
        lvi = visParent as ListViewItem;
        visParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visParent);
    }
    if (lvi == null) { return; }
    lvi.IsSelected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- I didn't check **Rekshino** solution
- Thank you for the tips, in the meantime during fighting with the problem I made so many changes that completely change viewmodel / view.
  I achieved my goal in that way:

**View:**

```
<Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding listCategoryAddValue}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Content="Add Value" Command="{Binding Path=AddValue}"/> 
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category.Name}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ValueList}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class CategoriesViewModel : WszystkieViewModel<CategoryAddValue>
    {
        #region Fields & Properties
        private ObservableCollection<CategoryAddValue> _listCategoryAddValue;
        public ObservableCollection<CategoryAddValue> listCategoryAddValue
        {
            get
            {
                if (_listCategoryAddValue == null) { Load(); }
                return _listCategoryAddValue;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_listCategoryAddValue != value)
                {
                    _listCategoryAddValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(() => listCategoryAddValue);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion Fields & Properties

        #region Constructor
        public CategoriesViewModel() : base()
        {
            base.DisplayName = "Kategorie";
        }
        #endregion Constructor

        #region Helpers
        private void SendValue(int CategoryId)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send(CategoryValueCode.AddValue + "," + CategoryId);
        }

        public override void Load()
        {
            var allCategories = (from k in db.Category select k).ToList();
            _listCategoryAddValue = new ObservableCollection<CategoryAddValue>();

            foreach (var i in allCategories)
            {
                _listCategoryAddValue.Add(new CategoryAddValue(new RelayCommand(() => SendValue(i.KategoriaId)))
                {
                    Category = i,
                    ValueList = db.CategoryValue.Where(x => x.CategoryId== i.CategoryId).Select(x => x.Value).ToList()
                });
            }
        }
        #endregion Helpers
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class CategoryAddValue
{
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public List<string> ValueList { get; set; }

    private ICommand _addValue;
    public ICommand AddValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _addValue;
        }
    }

    public CategoryAddValue(RelayCommand command)
    {
        _addValue = command;
    }
}
```